# Determinar la escala de un numero, en determinada tabla de multiplicación

Tags: javascript, lógica

**Hola**, gracias de antemano por la ayuda. Estoy realizando una función JavaScript con el siguiente funcionamiento. Creo una función llamada `DeterminarEscala(numero,multiplicando);` Esta función recibe como primer parámetro cualquier numero entero y el segundo parámetro es el numero de la tabla de multiplicar.

Ejemplo de funcionamiento con el numero 4:

`DeterminarEscala(1,4);` Debería retornar 1, por que el `1` esta en la siguiente escala **1**`,2,3,4 y 1*4= 4`

`DeterminarEscala(2,4);` Debería retornar 1, por que el `2` esta en la siguiente escala `1,`**2**`,3,4 y 1*4= 4`

`DeterminarEscala(3,4);` Debería retornar 1, por que el `3` esta en la siguiente escala `1,2,`**3**`,4 y 1*4= 4`

`DeterminarEscala(5,4);` Debería retornar 2, por que el `5` esta en la siguiente escala **5**`,6,7,8 y 2*4= 8`

`DeterminarEscala(6,4);` Debería retornar 2, por que el `6` esta en la siguiente escala `5,`**6**`,7,8 y 2*4= 8`

`DeterminarEscala(7,4);` Debería retornar 2, por que el `7` esta en la siguiente escala `5,6,`**7**`,8 y 2*4= 8`

`DeterminarEscala(9,4);` Debería retornar 3, por que el `9` esta en la siguiente escala **9**`,10,11,12 y 3*4= 12`

`DeterminarEscala(10,4);` Debería retornar 3, por que el `10` esta en la siguiente escala `9,`**10**`,11,12 y 3*4= 12`

`DeterminarEscala(11,4);` Debería retornar 3, por que el `11` esta en la siguiente escala `9,10,`**11**`,12 y 3*4= 12`

Ese seria un ejemplo del funcionamiento correcto de la función.

Ahora comparto el código que estoy trabajando:

```js
function DeterminarEscala(entero,multiplicador){
let r= entero/multiplicador;
r= Math.round(r);
console.log(r);
return r
};

let ensayo= DeterminarEscala(7,4);
console.log(ensayo);
```

```html
<input type="number" onkeyup="DeterminarEscala(this.value,5)">
```

Este código, funciona en parte. Pero da un resultado incorrecto en casos como:

- 1 y 4 retorna 0 debería ser 1
- 5 y 4 retorna 1 debería ser 2
- 9 y 4 retorna 2 debería ser 3

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución al problema planteado es la siguiente:

La función `DeterminarEscala(numero,multiplicando);` usa `Math.round` para redondear el resultado de la división de entero y multiplicador, para así calcular la escala del numero en la tabla de multiplicar. Esta función no daba el resultado correcto por que usa `Math.round`, esto retorna el valor de un número redondeado al entero más cercano. Por ello, al redondear números menores a 0.5 el resultado era 0.

El problema se soluciono reemplazando `Math.round` por `Math.ceil`. Este ultimo devuelve el entero mayor o igual más próximo a un número dado, lo que permitió hacer el calculo exacto de la escala de un numero en determinada tabla de multiplicar.

Aquí el código correcto:

```js
function DeterminarEscala(entero,multiplicador){
let r= entero/multiplicador;
r= Math.ceil(r);
console.log(r);
return r
};

//let ensayo= DeterminarEscala(7,4);
//console.log(ensayo);
```

```html
<input type="number" onkeyup="DeterminarEscala(this.value,4)">
```

Comment: Buenisimo!! recuerda aceptarla pasadas las 24 horas!